# get data from the api NY Times

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have API Data (ny times article) ,I need get data from the list inside another list ... and the api style like that :

```
result [{
.
.
.
"media": [
      {
.
.
.
"media-metadata:[
   {
    "url":"............",

    }]
  }] 
}
```

so how can get the url from media-metadata ?
and I use packages :

```
flutter_bloc

build_runner:
analyzer:
built_value_generator:
```

to generate files and methods
I need the url from the api to display photos on the screen of application

I made 3 classes the first class is the basic one (article) and class for media & another class for media-metadata now how can collect the data from each other ?

Comment: A good way is to use freezed and json serializable packages to map the API responses/deserialize  and use the auto generated getters to fetch the data and future builder would be an ideal way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object from the json response and access the list from it .
check [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) just paste your json response and it will do the work.

Comment: yes I can do that but Quicktype is not support the null safety